Proof that a limit is unique using the notion of "arbitrarily small"
This proof is from Vector Calculus by Susan Jane Colley and I wanted to understand the final argument.
For the below statements
$$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{a}}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{L}\\
\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{a}}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{M}
$$
The proof states that $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ where $\delta_i$ satisfies the requirement that $|| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{a}|| < \delta_i$ for each of the above statements so that $|| \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{L}|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|| \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{M}|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ meaning that both terms are smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and via the triangle inequality
$$
\begin{align}
||\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{M}||  & = || (\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{M}) + (\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}))|| \\
& \leq ||\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{f(x)}|| + ||\mathbf{f(x)} - \mathbf{M}||\\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
& = \epsilon
\end{align}
$$
The final line of the proof reads, "this shows that the quantity $||\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{M}||$ can be made arbitrarily small; thus it follows that $\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{M}$"
What I do not immediately follow is that since the quantity can be made arbitrarily small then $\mathbf{L} - \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{M}$. Could someone explain this please? My understanding is that arbitrarily small means it can be small but not zero.

Among the non-negative numbers, which number can be less than any positive number?

Just to note (re: "I am not sure how frequently something like this would occur/be relevant"), the argument "If $L$ and $M$ are real, then $L = M$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $|L - M| < \epsilon$" effectively characterizes the field of analysis. :)

Thank you @AndrewD.Hwang - a proper treatment of analysis will be my next stop. For someone with more comfortability with applied math, would you have a recommendation? I have the "Baby Rudin" book and thought I might start there

Principles of Mathematical Analysis is a fairly steep introduction, especially for self-study (though it's an excellent book). Spivak's Calculus is perhaps friendlier while still being logically rigorous. And there are many free (gratis) possibilities, including AMS Open Math Notes (I have a one-semester book titled Principles of Analysis that aims for friendliness, but there are multiple others), AIM textbooks, G.H. Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics from Project Gutenberg, ....

Suppose $||\mathbf{L}-\mathbf{M}|| = a > 0$. Then you can choose $\epsilon = a/2$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Thank you. I see the contradiction here now. More generally, in such scenarios where we have an inequality and the term arbitrarily small, is this fair to assume? Though I am not sure how frequently something like this would occur/be relevant.

You're welcome. I have seen many proofs use this kind of reasoning.

Following Halsey Royden's good advice to forge direct logical relationships where possible, we might think of this as an argument by contraposition ("If $|L - M| > 0$, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that [...]," proves the hypothesis "For every $\epsilon > 0$, [...]" is false) rather than an argument by contradiction. ;)
